# Why does DeviceIoControl throw error 21 (Device Not Ready) from C# when the equivalent in C works fine?

Tags: c#, c, windows-mobile, gps, pinvoke

I'm trying to send an IOCTL_SERVICE_REFRESH command to the GPS Intermediate Driver service using C# like this:

```
handle = CreateFile("GPD0:",
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
    IntPtr.Zero);

if (handle.ToInt32() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    rc = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    return rc;
}

int numBytesReturned = 0;

rc = DeviceIoControl(
    handle,
    IOCTL_SERVICE_REFRESH,
    null,
    0,
    null,
    0,
    ref numBytesReturned,
    IntPtr.Zero);

int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

GetLastWin32Error always gives me error 21 (device not ready). However, the equivalent call when made from C++ works fine:

```
HANDLE hGPS = CreateFile(L"GPD0:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if (hGPS != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  BOOL ret = DeviceIoControl(hGPS,IOCTL_SERVICE_REFRESH,0,0,0,0,0,0);
  DWORD err = GetLastError();       
}
```

I suspected a problem with the PInvoke signatures, but I can't seem to find anything wrong here:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int DeviceIoControl(
    IntPtr hDevice,
    uint dwIoControlCode,
    byte[] lpInBuffer,
    int nInBufferSize,
    byte[] lpOutBuffer,
    int nOutBufferSize,
    ref int lpBytesReturned,
    IntPtr lpOverlapped);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    String lpFileName,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode,
    IntPtr attr,
    uint dwCreationDisposition,
    uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the C version works? The docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx) say "If lpOverlapped is NULL, lpBytesReturned cannot be NULL. Even when an operation returns no output data and lpOutBuffer is NULL, DeviceIoControl makes use of lpBytesReturned." and you're passing NULL (0) for that parameter in your C call.

Comment: Your code declares the C# P/Invoke to have a ref parameter, yet the calling code passes nothing as a ref parameter, so I'm guessing what you've posted here eitehr won't compile or you have another overloaded declaration.  In any case, we don't have the full story.

Comment: @Gabe, I don't think that the parameter is a requirement in CE.  I certainly don't recall ever *having* to pass it (though maybe I've never tried not passing it).

Comment: ctacke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898288.aspx doesn't say anything indicating that `lpBytesReturned` is optional, so I would assume that it isn't.

Comment: @ctacke, it does pass a ref parameter and it does compile. Perhaps you didn't notice that the order of the PInvoke declarations is not the same as the order of the calls made in the sample code :)

Comment: @Gabe, I tried IOCTL_SERVICE_STATUS, gave it an output buffer and it populates fine in C. Same thing in C# still throws error 21 as before.

Comment: @Ragesh - I'm still confused.  `rc` is assigned the result of GetLastWin32Error, indicating it's an int.  You also use it for the return from DeviceIoControl, which returns a BOOL (admittedly 32-bit).  That seems like a mismatch. You also aren't looking at the return value from DeviceIoControl to see if it actually failed.  Checking the last error when there is no indication of actual failure is meaningless.

Comment: The DeviceIOControl() calls in your C and C# examples are possibly not, at a technical level, the same. I am not sure what the marshalling will do if you pass in 'Null' as opposed to an empty byte array ...?